# How to change mouse hovering background in Emacs

Tags: emacs

When mouse is over a Dired file line, it shows strange background regardless of the `highlight-line` color. I know there is something to do with theme.

How can I set the background color?

My Emacs config https://github.com/jilen/prelude

[image]

Comment: Do you get the same effect if you start `emacs -q`? If not, show us the content of your init file. Do you have resources that affect Emacs? (If you don't know what that is, you probably don't.)

Comment: @Gilles Yes, I've restarted Emacs many times. I guess it relateds to gtk/emacs theme. Here's the theme I use [this theme](https://github.com/jilen/prelude/blob/master/themes/base16-default-light-theme.el)

Comment: The question is, do you get the same effect **if you start Emacs with `emacs -q`**?

Comment: @Gilles No, Run `emacs -q` and the background is not black

Comment: Then **post your init file** (`.emacs` or `init.el` and any other file that they include).

Comment: @Gilles I've add link to my config